# How do I create a system of arrays that get the user input?

Tags: java, input, invoice

So I am creating an invoice generator, and I need the user to first say how many items they will input and then ask for item description(string), amount(int), and price(int). I was having trouble creating arrays for these infos. So far, I only created methods for them like here:

```
public static int itemDescription(){
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  String descr = input.nextInt();    
  return(descr);
}  

public static int quantitySold(){
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  int quansold = input.nextInt();    
  return(quansold);
 }

public static int unitPrice(){
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Unit Price:");                
  int price = input.nextInt();
  return(price);
 }
```

But if the user has more than one items to input, then I will need to use arrays as these will not be able to store more than one piece of data. 
(I made them separate methods because I will need the info separately later to calculate certain taxes on them.)

How could I turn those input functions into arrays?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about you add the inputs to Lists. Then you may convert the list to an array if you wish but you don't have to:

```
public void getInfo(int itemCount) {
  List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<Integer> sold = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> unitPrices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    descriptions.add(itemDescription());
    sold.add(quantitySold());
    unitPrices.add(unitPrice());
  }
}
```

Worth noting here - your itemDescription() method returns an int instead of a String. You might want to change it.

You could also create an `Item` class containing all the attributes you want. And for each attribute you want to do an `item.getInput()` for `itemCount` number of times!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise making an `Item` class so that the description, amount, and price of each item can be stored in a single object:

```
public class Item {

    String description;
    int amount;
    int price;

    public Item(String desc, int amt, int p) {
        description = desc;
        amount = amt;
        price = p;
    }
}
```

Then, something like this should work within your main method:

```
Item[] items;
String desc;
int amt;
int price;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many items? ");

while (true) {
    try {
        items = new Item[input.nextInt()];
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer! ");
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    // prompt user to input the info and assign info to desc, amt, and p
    items[i] = new Item(desc, amt, p);
}
```

I'd also like to point out that you do NOT need to create a separate `Scanner` for each method. If you wish to include methods like the ones you posted, you should either get the values and then pass them to the method, or just pass the existing `Scanner` to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public class Invoice {

    int ItemId;
    String Description;
    int Amount;
    int Price;

    Invoice(int itemId, String description, int amount, int price){

        this.ItemId = itemId;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Amount = amount;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public int Get_ItemId() {
        return this.ItemId;
    }

    public String Get_Description() {
        return this.Description;
    }

    public int Get_Amount() {
        return this.Amount;
    }

    public int Get_Price() {
        return this.Price;
    }
} 

....
ArrayList<Invoice> Invoices = new ArrayList<>();  

// Add invoice for 2 leather belts of $10 each
Invoices.add(new Invoice(Invoices.size(), "Leather Belt", 2, 10));

....
// Get invoice info
int itemid = Invoices.get(0).Get_ItemId;
```